# In C#, why are circular dependencies allowed in initializers for static fields?

Tags: c#

For static fields, circular dependencies result in the default value.

```
static int a = b; // 0
static int b = a; // 0
```

It doesn't apply to instance fields though, as they cannot reference each other.

```
int c = d; // CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property
int d = c; // CS0236
```

Why is this allowed for static fields?

Comment: It's not that circular references aren't allowed for non-static fields. It's that _no_ non-static members are allowed for non-static fields.

Comment: _"Why is this allowed for static fields?"_ -- what kind of answer would satisfy you? The specification clearly allows this for static fields and not for non-static fields. What do you want beyond that? Are you looking for a full rationalization from the language design team?

Comment: I don't think what you've shown there is a circular dependence.

Comment: A circular dependency would apply more to properties than fields. The following is legal, but will cause a `StackOverflowException` if you try to access either property at runtime: `class Foo { public static int a => b; public static int b => a; }`

Comment: I guess this isn't a circular dependency after all, unless they were properties instead. Are `a` and `b` guaranteed to be 0, or are they unspecified values?

Answer (score 3):

It is not circular dependency but the difference in how static and instance fields are initialized.

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the
>   instance being created. Thus it is a compile-time error to reference
>   this in a variable initializer, because it is a compile-time error for
>   a variable initializer to reference any instance member through a
>   simple-name

In short, you can't reference instance variable before it is created.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I saw this question with +4 votes. Never thought it's such an easy question. I misunderstood the question, but I think my answer is still helpful so I'm not going to delete it.

It's not a circular dependencies problem. Why the first example is allowed? Just consider this:

In a method, this is ok:

```
int a;
int b;
a = b;
b = a;
```

but this is not allowed:

```
int c;
c = d;
int d;
d = c;
```

And the order of *declarations* of fields/methods in a class is not important (but *definitions* have order)

Comment: @RufusL Edited.

Comment: In a method, the first code example doesn't compile, as `b` is not assigned (in C, it would cause undefined behavior, but implementations would probably use whatever was on the stack). But static fields can somehow be referenced before they are assigned. I wonder if it's guaranteed to be the default value or if it's just implementation-defined to be zero.

Comment: @Victor It's guaranteed to be the default value: null for [Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) and 0 for normal [Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)